# VS Code not showing auto-complete suggestions for Eigen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, eigen3

I recently downloaded Eigen 3.4.0. I have added it locally to the project I created. However, I am getting the red squiggly lines with the drag-over error - namespace "Eigen" has no member "VectorXd".[image: Picture with the red squiggly lines]

I tried adding the path of Eigen to c_cpp_properties.json, settings.json as well as tasks.json to no avail. I was expecting to get the auto-complete suggestions but to no avail.

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "eigen-3.4.0/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "__bit_reference": "cpp",
        "__bits": "cpp",
        "__config": "cpp",
        "__debug": "cpp",
        "__errc": "cpp",
        "__hash_table": "cpp",
        "__locale": "cpp",
        "__mutex_base": "cpp",
        "__node_handle": "cpp",
        "__nullptr": "cpp",
        "__split_buffer": "cpp",
        "__string": "cpp",
        "__threading_support": "cpp",
        "__tree": "cpp",
        "__tuple": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "atomic": "cpp",
        "bitset": "cpp",
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "chrono": "cpp",
        "clocale": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "compare": "cpp",
        "complex": "cpp",
        "concepts": "cpp",
        "cstdarg": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "cstdint": "cpp",
        "cstdio": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "cstring": "cpp",
        "ctime": "cpp",
        "cwchar": "cpp",
        "cwctype": "cpp",
        "deque": "cpp",
        "exception": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "ios": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "istream": "cpp",
        "limits": "cpp",
        "list": "cpp",
        "locale": "cpp",
        "map": "cpp",
        "memory": "cpp",
        "mutex": "cpp",
        "new": "cpp",
        "optional": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "queue": "cpp",
        "ratio": "cpp",
        "set": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp",
        "stdexcept": "cpp",
        "streambuf": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "system_error": "cpp",
        "tuple": "cpp",
        "type_traits": "cpp",
        "typeinfo": "cpp",
        "unordered_map": "cpp",
        "variant": "cpp",
        "vector": "cpp",
        "algorithm": "cpp"
    },

    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "eigen-3.4.0/**"
    ],

    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default",
    
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
}
```

EDIT: The code compiles and runs absolutely fine through the terminal. The problem is purely with getting the auto-suggestions.

EDIT 2: The answer which was suggested does not answer my question. I have already added the path to includePath and <Eigen/Dense> is recognised. However, intelliSense does not give auto-suggestions for Eigen. My problem is specific to Eigen.

Comment: Have you tried to add the setting via UI?

Try this: Press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`P`
Select `C/C++: Edit Configs (UI)`

In the "include path" list, add the Eigen Headers

Should look like this: https://i.imgur.com/30O6n1u.png

Comment: The entire Eigen folder is already in the workspace. Nonetheless, I had already added the path to Eigen. IntelliSense still does not recognise Eigen data types nor does it give any IntelliSense suggestions.